# Apache requests waterfall

Tags: apache, request

In normal mode my apache mod status shows this:

```
CPU Usage: u118.45 s9.79 cu0 cs0 - 14% CPU load
7.96 requests/sec - 18.1 kB/second - 2331 B/request
1 requests currently being processed, 29 idle workers
._.._._..._.___...._____...._.____.._.._.._....___._._____W.....
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
....................................................
```

But sometimes (period about 1-3 minutes) my site has "lags", and the apache status looks like this:

```
CPU Usage: u222.29 s18.89 cu0 cs0 - 9.58% CPU load
7.77 requests/sec - 23.3 kB/second - 3064 B/request
20 requests currently being processed, 10 idle workers
WW.WW_W..WWC.._W.WCWW._._.W....WW_W..W__.W__...._...W...........
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
....................................................
```

During these moments, requests are usual, as at any time. But there are a lot of them.
I don't have any cron jobs that are this frequent.

Increasing prefork SpareServers mb will help, but i want to know why these waves are happening.
My current config is

```
Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 200
KeepAliveTimeout 20

<IfModule prefork.c>
  StartServers       100
  MinSpareServers    10
  MaxSpareServers   30
  ServerLimit      500
  MaxClients       500
  MaxRequestsPerChild  10000
</IfModule>
```

The hardware is strong enough.

Sorry for my bad English.
Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Whatevers generating the response (guessing mod_php since you use prefork) has slowed down.  There's nothing you can tune in the webserver to not be tied up by your application

Comment: so problem not in apache? i should see somth like php or mysql perfomance (bandwith - another word idk) u think? the real question was why this WAVES arrives. i thoutght the problem was apache or some os config (mb nginx but here i donbt see any problems), becouse requests are usuall. still sory for my bad eng